# Using Extract-Text-Webpack-Plugin with Vue CLI 3

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I've created an app using the Vue CLI, which now abstracts Webpack config behind vue.config.js. I'm trying to extract my CSS to a styles.css file. Right now, it's extracting to randomly named files, like this:

dist\js\vendor.4ee179da.js    74.69 kb               26.68 kb
dist\js\app.5e840ed0.js       4.06 kb                1.84 kb
dist\css\app.4c22f75b.css     161.13 kb              21.59 kb

I suspect my css.extract needs to be an object, like

```
{
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

But adding this breaks the build with  new _ValidationError2.default(ajv.errors, name).

Below is my vue.config.js:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    // Project deployment base
    // By default we assume your app will be deployed at the root of a domain,
    // e.g. https://www.my-app.com/
    // If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that
    // sub-path here. For example, if your app is deployed at
    // https://www.foobar.com/my-app/
    // then change this to '/my-app/'
    baseUrl: '/',

    // where to output built files
    outputDir: 'dist',

    // whether to use eslint-loader for lint on save.
    // valid values: true | false | 'error'
    // when set to 'error', lint errors will cause compilation to fail.
    lintOnSave: true,

    // use the full build with in-browser compiler?
    // https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only
    compiler: false,

    // generate sourceMap for production build?
    productionSourceMap: true,

    // tweak internal webpack configuration.
    // see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/webpack.md
    chainWebpack: () => {},
    configureWebpack: () => {
        new ExtractTextPlugin('assets/style.css')
    },

    // CSS related options
    css: {
        // extract CSS in components into a single CSS file (only in production)
        // can also be an object of options to pass to extract-text-webpack-plugin
        extract: true,

        // Enable CSS modules for all css / pre-processor files.
        // This option does not affect *.vue files.
        modules: true,

        // enable CSS source maps?
        sourceMap: false,

        // pass custom options to pre-processor loaders. e.g. to pass options to
        // sass-loader, use { sass: { ... } }
        loaderOptions: {
            sass:{
                css: 'css-loader',
                'scss':'css-loader | sass-loader'
            }
        }
    },

    // use thread-loader for babel & TS in production build
    // enabled by default if the machine has more than 1 cores
    parallel: require('os').cpus().length > 1,

    // options for the PWA plugin.
    // see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa
    pwa: {},

    // configure webpack-dev-server behavior
    devServer: {
        open: process.platform === 'darwin',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 8082,
        https: false,
        hotOnly: false,
        // See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/cli-service.md#configuring-proxy
        proxy: null, // string | Object
        before: app => {}
    },

    // options for 3rd party plugins
    pluginOptions: {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed it. Here is the proper way to do it. Under CSS, change extract to:

```
extract: {filename: 'styles.css'}
```

I kept the loaderOptions, sourceMap and modules objects in there, which seems to work fine.

Comment: I know this is may be a bit old. I am building a library using vue-cli 3. to make CSS works fine when I add the library into the app I need to import the css separately. Is there a way to import the library and css comes together?

Answer (score 4):

Vue CLI 3 actually uses `mini-css-extract-plugin`, not `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

When you are passing in `extract: {filename: 'styles.css'}` you are actually configuring `mini-css-extract-plugin`. You can see those docs [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract).

You can set the `filename` for `mini-css-extract-plugin` ([docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin%23minimal-example)). [Here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/css.js#L26) is where Vue is passing that in.

You should be able to remove all references to `extract-text-webpack-plugin` and your code will continue to work fine!